# Writing to a file using fprintf in c

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to write to a file in my program, but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I could be using `fscanf` incorrectly which is very possible.

I need to write the unsolved puzzle to a file to see if I'm getting the file into my code correctly, but like a said I'm not sure if I'm even using `fscanf` correctly. (the puzzle file is in my Clionfile to I know that not the problem.)

Here is my section of my program that I am using for reading.

```
int read(const char *name, int **problem, int **z, int *size) {
    int n;
    int *p;
    int *c;
    FILE* input;

    input = fopen("name", "r");
    fscanf(input,"%d", &n);

    *size = n;
    p = (int *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int)); /* nxn grid has n*n elements*/
    c = (int *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
    *problem = p;
    *z = c;

    input = fopen(name, "r");
    fprintf(input, "%d\n", n);
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

All I need to know is where I have gone wrong or if my problem isn't with this.

Comment: That `fprintf` is guaranteed fail. You opened the fie in read-only mode. Also, unless `name == "name"`, those are two different files anyway. You also never closed the original opened `input` result, so that's a blatant leak.And even if you fix both, that `fprintf` followed by the close will strip the entire file except the number you sent, so I hope that was the intent. You also never check the result of `fscan` to see if it succeeded, nor even check the result of `fopen` to see if it returned NULL. Summary: *most* of this code is wrong in one form or another.

Comment: when calling C library functions, like `fopen()` `fscanf()`, etc, always check for any error indication.  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `p=(int *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(int)); /* nxn grid has n*n elements*/
   c= (int*)malloc (n*n*sizeof(int));`  the function: `malloc()` expects its parameter to be of type `size_t`, not an `int` so both of these statements will result in the compiler outputting a warning message

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1):

I really did not follow your code completely, but have created a version that compiles and runs. I have added a couple of asserts to show what values I was expecting.  I find these helpful to confirm to me what I expect the program to do.

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <itclInt.h>
#include <assert.h>


int ReadFile(const char *name, int **problem, int **z, int *size) {
    int n;
    int *p;
    int *c;
    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;

    /* Open file "name" for reading and writing */
    output = fopen(name, "w");
    assert(output != NULL);

    fprintf(output, "%d", *size);
    if(fclose(output) == EOF)
        perror ("fclose-input");

    /* Open file "name" for reading and writing */
    input = fopen(name, "r");
    assert(input != NULL);

    /* Get integer input from the file and store it in n. */
    fscanf(input, "%d", &n);
    assert(n == *size);
    if(fclose(input) == EOF)
        perror ("fclose-input");

    p = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int)); /* nxn grid has n*n elements*/
    c = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
    *problem = p;
    *z = c;

    input=fopen(name,"w");
    fprintf(input,"%d\n",n);
    if(fclose(input) == EOF)
        perror ("fclose-input");
    return 0 ;

}


int main() {
    int size = 5;
    int* problemIntPtr;
    int* zintPtr;

    ReadFile("name.txt", &problemIntPtr, &zintPtr, &size);
    printf("We made it!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two nits (1) there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), and (2) it is a good idea to check the return of `fclose` *after writing*, e.g. after the `fprintf` write, `if (fclose (input) == EOF) perror ("fclose-input");` to catch any stream errors or error that occurred after the return of `fprintf` was processed.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Updated with your suggestions.  Thank you!